# JIRA/Greenhopper Handling patch releases?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

We have the following scenario that we'd like to solve.

1. We create a new sprint, call it sprint "A" with a bunch of issues.
2. Then, we get a call from a customer which results in an emergency patch needing to be released.

Here, we'd like to create a new sprint for the patch, and move it to the top of the planning board.  We're unable to do this.

I tried to create a second planning board in an attempt to solve this, but it seems like we cannot have two sprints going at once.

How should we handle this scenario of wanting to create a "patch" release cycle?

EDIT - Another thing I could do is run simultaneous sprints, but I don't know how to do it, and the post I found was not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the new issue for the emergency patch to the existing sprint and rank it to the top so it will be done first? You could even configure an 'Emergency' swimlane to appear at the top of the board which guarantees that emergency issues would be shown with the highest priority.

If you really want to create a separate sprint for the Emergency fix you should enable Parallel Sprints (there's some information on this in the [release notes](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/GreenHopper+6.0.3+Release+Notes#GreenHopper6.0.3ReleaseNotes-Parallelsprints), please ensure you're running GreenHopper 6.0.3 or above). Once you do this you'll be able to start another sprint on the same board as your existing running sprint.

Thanks,
Shaun